# Proving that a quantity of a central potential is conserved

Tags: vector-analysis

I am trying to show that $K= m \vec{r} \cdot \dot{\vec{v}} -2Et $ is a conserved quantity within a central-potential $U(r) = \frac{\Gamma}{r^2}$ with $\Gamma >0$.

The issue that I have isn't in the physics of the problem, but a certain step of the solution which I don't understand. (Since I wasn't able to solve it on my own, I want to understand the solution.)

Namely, in order to show that some quantity is conserved we must show that $\frac{d}{dt}[K] = 0$. After some "physical" substitutions the textbook arrives at the expression:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}[K] = -2\frac{\Gamma}{r^2}-\vec{r} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \left( \frac{\Gamma}{r^2} \right)
$$

What I don't understand is, that they write in the next line, that the above is equal to:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}[K] = -2\frac{\Gamma}{r^2}-\vec{r} \cdot \frac{\vec{r}}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( \frac{\Gamma}{r^2} \right)
$$

I first suspected that it is obviously the chain rule, however, it doesn't seem to be it. Because, for instance with the chain rule, you would get a negative sign in front of the second term (i.e. the second term would become positive).

Then I thought they multiply by a $"1"$ vector to use it in the next calculation. But $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$ isn't a $"1"$ and thus, if I am not mistaken cannot just be multiplied to the equation.

So my question is what is happening between those two lines.

All help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because the gradient of $1/(r^2)$ is purely radial. So you can write the gradient of that whole thing only as derivative with respect to $r$ multiplied by the radial unit vector $\hat{r}=\dfrac{\vec{r}}{r}$.

Comment: @Leonid, thanks for you answer. Could you elaborate on that where form does the unit vector come from? What I also don't understand is why doesn't the unit vector change the result. I mean it has the length 1 but isn't 1 in all components...

Comment: I elaborated downwards; hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of a function in spherical coordinates read:

$$\nabla f= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} \hat{r} + \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \hat{\theta} + \dfrac{1}{rsin(\theta)} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \hat{\phi}$$

If you  are not aware of this formula you can just read it as:

$$\nabla f= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} \hat{r} + \text{other terms depending on $\theta$ and $\phi$}$$

Since in your case $$f=\dfrac{\Gamma}{r^2}$$

which doesn't depend on $\theta$ or $\phi$ then in your specific case we have:

$$\nabla \Big( \dfrac{\Gamma}{r^2}\Big)= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r} \Big( \dfrac{\Gamma}{r^2} \Big) \hat{r}$$

So you see the unit vector comes from the fact that the gradient of a function is a vector function. Hence you need vectors to express it; since your field is radial then spherical coordinates are uniquely suited to describe that; spherical coordinate vectors naturally come with a radial vector with respect to which $\nabla f$ has components.